# vim + minibufexplorer causing my screens to split unevenly

Tags: vim

Before I installed minibufexplorer, my vim screens would split evenly.

2 open = 50/50 (% width)

3 open = 33/33/33 (% width)

4 open = 25/25/25/25 (% width)

After I installed minibufexplorer, when I split a window it halves the current window so I get

2 open = 50/50 (% width)

3 open = 50/25/25 (% width)

etc

I have scoured the net for information with no luck.

Anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the plugin's code, and found this:

```
" !!! We may want to make the following optional -- Bindu
" New windows don't cause all windows to be resized to equal sizes
set noequalalways
```

This setting controls the behaviour you specify. The only way I can see for you to solve your problem is to ask the plugin maintainers for a fix. The plugin seems not to be maintained by its original author, but there's a github project that continues it, I think: https://github.com/fholgado/minibufexpl.vim. You can file an issue on the bug tracker here: https://github.com/fholgado/minibufexpl.vim/issues.

As for why it's setting that option, I assume it's necessary, because minibufexpl opens up a new, small buffer with a list of the open buffers. If the setting was on, that buffer would be resized as well, which would be undesirable. I think it's avoidable by using `winfixheight` (the github version seems to use that), but I can't really tell, I don't use the plugin. One thing I can suggest is to find the plugin in your vimfiles and comment out the `set noequalalways` line, see if everything still works. If it does, you could ask the plugin authors to remove it entirely.

Comment: hey thanks for looking into this. I tried to comment out that line but it leads to some undesirable behavior. The Tab window resizes all the time to half the available height. I'm just going to disable minibufexpl for now, I don't really use it anyway